# Refused to connect 'https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/' in a frame because AWS is 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'

Tags: amazon-s3, frame, content-security-policy, x-frame-options

I currently just use an AWS S3 Bucket to be able to show some of my HTML canvas animations, and never had issues until I created an iFrame for an ad platform that versions using a feed called Celtra.

I tried ?embed=true and target="_blank" mentioned in another question where the policy was SAMEDOMAIN, and not surprisingly neither worked.

Do I need to use a Create Object Lambda Access Point? According to Mozilla, DENY & SAMEORIGIN are the only option.

ALLOW-FROM uri
This is an obsolete directive that no longer works in modern browsers. Don't use it. In supporting legacy browsers, a page can be displayed in a frame only on the specified origin uri. Note that in the legacy Firefox implementation this still suffered from the same problem as SAMEORIGIN did — it doesn't check the frame ancestors to see if they are in the same origin. The Content-Security-Policy HTTP header has a frame-ancestors directive which you can use instead.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, you have to use [Lambda@Edge func](https://aws.amazon.com/ru/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/adding-http-security-headers-using-lambdaedge-and-amazon-cloudfront/) to add custom HTTP response headers to AWS S3 bucket.
   But judging by [this topic](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=534727), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61105557/aws-cloudfront-add-custom-header-without-using-lambdaedge), and [this doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/RequestAndResponseBehaviorCustomOrigin.html), AWS does not add `X-Frame-Options` header on its own. Therefore your HTML canvas animations should not be blocked in the iframe.
2. If you wish to allow iframing at miltiple locations, the `X-Frame-Options` is not flexible enough. Use `Conrent-Security-Policy` (CSP) HTTP header with the [`frame-ancestors`](https://csplite.com/csp76/) directive.

   `Conrent-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors *;`
   will allow iframing at any locations, while
   `Conrent-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors example.com friends.com;`
   allows to embed page have published this header only in `example.com` and `friends.com` sites only.

**UPDATE**

The HTTP header with white list of domains allowed to embed iframe:

```
`Conrent-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors example.com friends.com allowed_site.net`
```

must be published by your `s3.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/buckets/advancedbanners` page. This page should grant the permissions to embed itself.

I am not shure you can to publish CSP header on AWS S3 without Lambda@Edge func. You have to use exactly HTTP header, since `frame-ancestors` is not supported in the `<meta http-equiv="Conrent-Security-Policy" content=" directives_here ">` meta tag.

And you have to find a way to stop publishing the `X-Frame-Options`(XFO) header on AWS S3 because of [Safari bug](https://csplite.com/csp76/#bug_Safari_frame-ancestors_X-Frame-Options) - XFO does not obsolete in favor CSP.

Comment: Thanks granty!  1. The content in the iFrame is definitely being blocked. "Refused to display 'https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'. preview.0f7cfd35.min.js:1"  2. If I pursue "Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/buckets/advancedbanners" is this the proper format for just my S3 bucket? And do I still need to use Lambda@Edge func?

Comment: Pls see UPDATED answer, because a lot of info.