# Why CloudFront not deliver content-security-policy set in ResponseHeadersPolicy (2022)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

Amazon says we can use [CloudFront Response Headers Policies](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/amazon-cloudfront-introduces-response-headers-policies/) to set a Content Security Policy for a static/Angular web bundle served from S3 bucket.

To that end, I defined a policy (to allow src-style 'unsafe-inline'):
[image]

And attached it to my  distribution:
[image]

CloudFront console and API queries all confirm the policy is linked;
But when I access the content (curl or Chrome), the header still contains:

`content-security-policy: default-src 'none'; img-src 'self'; script-src 'self'; style-src 'self'; object-src 'none'`

(so Chrome rejects the style elements)

Cacheing is disabled.

I know CF has the updated policy:
I can set an alternate custom header on the origin (which works) and when I replace that with the CSP, the X-diddle header disappears, but the CSP does not replace it!)
TTBOMK there is no meta-data coming from the S3-Origin (but we say override, anyway)

What can I do to provoke CF to send the designated content-security-policy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. never mind:
There was a CloudFront *function* attached to the distributions which interpose on the Response and **that function was setting the content-security-policy**